# Is there a word that describes both Spring and Fall, but not other seasons?

Tags: word-choice, single-word-requests, seasons

"Wet seasons" or "cool seasons" don't apply everywhere, and "equinoctial seasons" blur into Winter. "Isothermal seasons"?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

How about [**transitional seasons**](http://cmapskm.ihmc.us/rid=1103742096094_776074520_7960/Transitional%20Seasons%20Weather%20Regime.cmap)?

Comment: That one is more common than "equinoctial" [since around 1940](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=equinoctial+seasons%2Ctransitional+seasons&case_insensitive=on&year_start=1800&year_end=2000&corpus=15&smoothing=0&share=&direct_url=t1%3B%2Cequinoctial%20seasons%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Ctransitional%20seasons%3B%2Cc0).

Comment: ["The tropical seasons are broken up into just two: the wet season and the dry season."](http://education.nationalgeographic.com/education/encyclopedia/tropics/?ar_a=1) - Don't they have Spring and Fall?

Comment: Correct, because a yearly [season](http://www.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/english/season) is not simply marked by Earth's angle regarding the sun.

Answer (score 2):

[**Equinoctial seasons**](https://www.google.com/search?q=%22equinoctial%20seasons%22&tbs=bks:1&lr=lang_en) is the [most accurate](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=wet+seasons%2Cequinoctial+seasons%2Ccool+seasons%2Cisothermal+seasons&case_insensitive=on&year_start=1800&year_end=2000&corpus=15&smoothing=1&share=&direct_url=t4%3B%2Cwet%20seasons%3B%2Cc0%3B%2Cs0%3B%3Bwet%20seasons%3B%2Cc0%3B%3BWet%20seasons%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Cequinoctial%20seasons%3B%2Cc0%3B.t4%3B%2Ccool%20seasons%3B%2Cc0%3B%2Cs0%3B%3Bcool%20seasons%3B%2Cc0%3B%3BCool%20seasons%3B%2Cc0); I checked the texts Google Ngrams found and all but "equinoctial seasons" were more about the weather than the time of year. "Isothermal seasons" was not found.

Comment: How does an Ngram prove its accuracy?